# Unhandled promise rejections and ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT

Tags: javascript, node.js

i'm trying to make a rest api server with node express and mysql, the structure of the requests is this:

this is the route

```
router.get('/api/courseDetails/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let levels = await db.levelsByCourseId(req.params.id)
        res.sendStatus(200).json(levels)
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        res.sendStatus(500)
    }
})
```

and this is the query:

```
requests.levelsByCourseId = (id) => {
    let query = "select * from levels where parent_course_id="+id+" and visibility>0"
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pool.query(query,(err, results) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err)
            }
            return resolve(results)
        })
    })
}
```

i use this structure also for other requests that works without errore, but this gives me this error:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:485:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\giuse\VScodeProjects\noderest-tutorial-server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\giuse\VScodeProjects\noderest-tutorial-server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:264:10)
    at C:\Users\giuse\VScodeProjects\noderest-tutorial-server\server\routes\index.js:47:29
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
(node:15588) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:485:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\giuse\VScodeProjects\noderest-tutorial-server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.contentType (C:\Users\giuse\VScodeProjects\noderest-tutorial-server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:599:15)
    at ServerResponse.sendStatus (C:\Users\giuse\VScodeProjects\noderest-tutorial-server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:357:8)
    at C:\Users\giuse\VScodeProjects\noderest-tutorial-server\server\routes\index.js:50:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(node:15588) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:15588) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

anyone could help me?
thank you

edit:
on the client side i have a promise and not some data (it is inside the promise)

```
Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: "OK"
```

and the axios code:

```
 static async getCourseDetails(id) {
        try {
            const data = await axios.get(basepath + '/api/courseDetails/' + id)
            return data.data
        } catch (error) {
            throw error;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used wrong method to **set** status before sending results to a client.
It should be like this:

```
res.status(200).json(levels)
```

Calling `setStatus` you actually do `res.status(200).send('OK')` and right after that you call `json` that also sets status 200 and send a result as JSON.

Comment: great, thank you, it is, but i have still the promise in the console instead the data: Promise {<pending>}, how can i solve?

Comment: on postman it works, now i think is a client side problem, maybe the await before axios

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in the way you send the response. In the `try` block you await the levels from the `db` and then use `sendStatus` set a status and with `json(levels)` send a response as JSON back.

But according to the docs of Express.js `sendStatus` does the following.

```
res.sendStatus(200) // equivalent to res.status(200).send('OK')
```

So the status is being sent as a response. And after that you send another response as JSON. This is what triggers the error.

Use `res.status(200)` instead to only set the status without sending it.

```
router.get('/api/courseDetails/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let levels = await db.levelsByCourseId(req.params.id)
        res.status(200).json(levels)
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        res.sendStatus(500)
    }
})
```